# Intune PowerShell: find devices where UPN is null

Tags: powershell, intune

I'm struggling a bit with the Intune Powershell cmdlets. I need to clean the devices list which contains thousands of *Intune registered* devices that have an enrolment date and no last-checking date (and therefore these would not be caught by the auto-purge).

I could easily retrieve the list of devices where the users had left our Azure AD by running this command:

```
$devices = Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "deviceName eq 'User deleted for this device'"
```

However I cannot get a working query to identify devices where the userPrincipalName (UPN) is null. I tried multiple variation of the filter and never got the same results as in the CSV. I copy below the variations I have tried:

```
$devices = Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'null'"
$devices = Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "'userPrincipalName' eq 'null'"
$devices = Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "userPrincipalName eq ''"
$devices = Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "'userPrincipalName' eq ''"
```

I have used the Intune Admin portal ([M365 Device Management](https://devicemanagement.microsoft.com/)) to filter and export these devices to at least get a CSV list. The CSV file indicates that the UPN is equal to "None".

If I then query a single device using another key from the CSV (like the managedDeviceId) then I get an object and I can confirm the UPN property is empty.

```
$item = Get-IntuneManagedDevice -managedDeviceId 1c0123a4-8324-48f7-b1c2-d4512345228a
$item
```

[image: $item device object properties]

Any advice ? 
What is wrong with the UPN-based query ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you try `Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "userPrincipalName eq ''"`

Comment: Same, nothing returned. I will update the question. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: I have no idea what kind of filter this command is using. Maybe piping to `Where-Object {!$_.UserPrincipalName}` or something similar will have better results.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for keeping this post alive after years.
This is how I managed to get the devices without UPN:

```
get-intunemanageddevice | Get-MSGraphAllPages | where "userprincipalname" -eq ''
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is a bit old, but I wanted to comment after running into this too. At least in my case, the issue is because 'userPrincpalName' and 'emailAddress' return the user who *enrolled* the device, not who's assigned to it. I've tried putzing around with Get-AzureADDevice and Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner but have yet to find a good way to combine them and get this result. I just exported everything through the GUI and filtered it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).